# How to generate Serial Number in reverse order with ROW_NUMBER() function in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL to generate Serial number in SQL server 2008

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Column ) AS SrNo
```

Above SQL will generate SrNo in the ascending order

> 1 2 3 4 5

but I want to generate it in descending order.

> 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort the ORDER BY column DESC

```
SELECT SrNo FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YOUR_COLUMN ) AS SrNo FROM YOUR_TABLE) X
ORDER BY SrNo DESC
```

Comment: Isn't any idea without using sub query?

Comment: Mostly No I guess !! Please anybody correct me if I am wrong (by providing example)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select * FROM (

  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SNO, ColumnName FROM table

 )r

 ORDER BY SNO Desc
```